# Connecting to mysql through Spyder

Tags: python, mysql, spyder

I am trying to connect to an online database through Spyder enviroment. For some reason it keeps on giving an error. Below is the code that I am using

```
import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=52.36.146.161,8100;DATABASE=gac_seo;uid=$$$$;pwd=$$$$$$')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select Select * From patients")
for row in cur:
   print
cur.close()
con.close()
```

It keeps on giving me the following error while connecting to the database:

> ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')

I have searched other threads with same problem but none of what they mentioned help me. Still have the same problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just did. Thanks

Comment: The question seems clear: Check the server and make sure you have access. Remember, `gac_seo@localhost` != `gac_seo@%`. Additionally, check the connection string: Should the port separated by comma?

Comment: I can access this through myphpadmin with the same id and pass. I was using ':' before but didn't work, saw someone using comma so I changed it too, hoping it was a minor problem.

Comment: Is phpmyadmin on the same box? Also: SQL Server != MySQL.

Comment: I think I was confusing sql server for mysql. I am now using mysql connector. It still isn't connecting and gives me a lost connection when I try to reach it but thats a diff story I guess. Thank you tho.